# Split the Master List base on child List LINQ

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have list classes as below. I need to slipt `List<TimeSheet>` base on `List<Activity>` count. If activity is greater than 8 then List split by two sublists along with List 0-7 and 7-onward. remain value should be the same in List like employee name and activity hours.

**More Detail:** I am adding some more detail.
Time has only one entry but internal Activity has 10 entries. I need to split the Time with two lists. the first-time list consumes 0-7 activity and another time list consumes 8-onward. So EmployeeName should be the same in both the child list. only Activity lists are different. In new lists, One list has 8 activity entries and another has 2 activity entries.

```
List<TimeSheet> Time;

сlass TimeSheet
{
    public string employeeName {get;set;}
    public List<Activity> activity {get;set;}
    public List<ActivityHours> ActivityHours{get;set;}
}

class Activity
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Activity {get;set;}
}

class ActivityHours
{
    public string ActivityId {get;set;}
    public string hours {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Start with a simple loop and then see what can be converted to LINQ, if can be and will still be efficient enough. Also please share what you already tried and what didn't work.

Comment: I am still working on it. my other system capacity is taking 8 records per rows and  I need to split my large activity list in 8 records per rows along with other values

Comment: Why did you delete the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67993607/datetime-now-not-working-with-savechanges-entityframework ?

Comment: @Enigmativity : I changed the datatype in sql server. varchar(50) is better option. rather then wasting of time with Datetime.

Comment: @SaroopTrivedi - Learning why it didn't work is a better investment in your future. Leave it up and maybe you'll get a good answer. And it might then help others - that's what the site is for.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about ActivityHours having the same reference across different chunks of activity you can use this code:

```
var newTime = Time
    .SelectMany(t =>
        Enumerable
        .Range(0, (t.activity.Count - 1) / 8)
        .Select(i => new TimeSheet
        {
            employeeName = t.employeeName,
            ActivityHours = t.ActivityHours,
            activity = t.activity.GetRange(i * 8, Math.Min(8, t.activity.Count))
        }))
    .ToList();
```

Note that `Enumerable.Range(0, count)` returns an `Enumerable<int>` like `[0, 1,... , count-1]`

and `(t.activity.Count - 1) / 8` is to not have a TimeSheet at the end with an empty activity in case the count was multiple of 8.

`activity.GetRange(i, count)` returns an `Enumerable<Activity>` with size of count starting from 'i'th element of activity

and `Math.Min(8, t.activity.Count)` is to prevent argument out of range.

if you want to make them independent, you can clone it:

```
var newTime = Time
    .SelectMany(t =>
        Enumerable
        .Range(0, (t.activity.Count - 1) / 8)
        .Select(i => new TimeSheet
        {
            employeeName = t.employeeName,
            ActivityHours = 
                (t.activity.Count < 8) ? 
                t.ActivityHours : 
                t.ActivityHours.Select(h => new ActivityHours
                {
                    ActivityId = h.ActivityId,
                    hours = h.hours
                }).ToList(),
            activity = t.activity.GetRange(i * 8, Math.Min(8, t.activity.Count))
        }))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The follwing is also doing the job, but in a different way than @Bizhan's solution

```
     List<TimeSheet> SplitList = 
        TimeList.Aggregate(new List<TimeSheet>(), 
                           (accList, timeSheet) =>
                           {
                              if ((timeSheet.Activities?.Count ?? 0) > 8)
                              {
                                 accList.Add(new TimeSheet 
                                             { 
                                                EmployeeName = timeSheet.EmployeeName, 
                                                ActivityHours = timeSheet.ActivityHours.ToList(), 
                                                Activities = timeSheet.Activities.GetRange(0, 8) 
                                             });
                                 accList.Add(new TimeSheet 
                                             { 
                                                EmployeeName = timeSheet.EmployeeName, 
                                                ActivityHours = timeSheet.ActivityHours, 
                                                Activities = timeSheet.Activities.GetRange(8, timeSheet.Activities.Count - 8) 
                                             });
                              }
                              else
                              {
                                 accList.Add(timeSheet);
                              }
                              return accList;
                           },
                           accList => accList);
```

Comment: ActivityHours = timeSheet.ActivityHours.ToList() will still reference the same ActivityHours objects, there is no need to ToList it again.

Answer (score 0):

This seems rather simple with `Take()` and `Skip()`.

```
List<TimeSheet> result = 
    Time
        .SelectMany(t => new []
        {
            new TimeSheet()
            {
                employeeName = t.employeeName,
                activity = t.activity.Take(8).ToList(),
                ActivityHours = t.ActivityHours,
            },
            new TimeSheet()
            {
                employeeName = t.employeeName,
                activity = t.activity.Skip(8).ToList(),
                ActivityHours = t.ActivityHours,
            },
        })
        .Where(t => t.activity.Any())
        .ToList();
```